# How to add Maven Youtube libraries to Android Gradle project?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-maven-plugin

A have some problem with adding external maven libraries to my Android Gradle project.

My application need Facebook SDK and YouTube API to work propertly. 
I just download facebook SDK, create module and add dependecies in Project Structure and it work perfectly. In the case of YouTube, Google does not provide gradle SDK, but only Maven sample project.

When I just import that project, Maven download all dependecies to external librares and I can run sample codes, but I can't use this in my android project.

My question is: How to add Maven Youtube libraries to Android Gradle project ?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: What is the maven equivalent? Can you provide the xml?

Comment: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/pom.xml

Comment: have you tried `compile com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev107-1.18.0-rc`

Comment: I'm surprised. I'm spending all night to try figure out that dependicies and answer was that basic and simple. That works. Thanks!

Comment: I added as an answer. I would appreciate it if you could accept it as an answer

Comment: I would like to, but I can't. _Vote Up requires 15 reputation._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried `compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev107-1.18.0-rc'`